# Open (download) file with multiple dots in name

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I have an ASP.NET application that generates a file. The problem is that this file has a name with multiple dots (for example: 52420.620993.20130910.010.epk). The name is in this format but the numbers are generated dynamically. If I try to "open" it via hyperlink or just put full adress in adress bar I get 404.3 error. I would like to open a download box and to download this file.

The file is there, I checked, but the problem is that it IIS won't recognise it.

BTW. I work with ASP.NET 4.0 and IIS 7.5

EDIT:
I have tryed UrlEncode but with no luck...
The code for opening the file is:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me, Me.GetType(), "anyKey", "<script>window.open('epk/" & HttpUtility.UrlEncode(filename) & ".epk');</script>", false)
```

I have also tryed to add this in the web config:

```
<system.web>
<httpRuntime relaxedUrlToFileSystemMapping="true" />
</system.web>
```

and:

```
<system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="ApiURIs-ISAPI-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Have you tried renaming the file? You can rename the file using `System.IO.File` class

Comment: URL encode the filename.

Comment: Dots shouldn't be a problem in an URL. Make sure there is not some other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, that problem is not in dots, try to check out extensions setup in iis, your `epk` extension should be added in avaliable extensions list. Add `epk` like described here http://geekswithblogs.net/frankw/archive/2008/04/10/configure-iis-to-host-silverlight-applications.aspx

Comment: This is a bit closer to a solution... The app is now recognising the file but it opens it in a new window. That is ok, but it would be better to open a download prompt... I put "application/octet-stream" in MIME type.

Answer (score 0):

Use encoded url to escape special characters.

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode
```